# how to get words from string without SPLIT in c#

Tags: c#, string

I'm stack with a task which ask for "read from console" (C#) a text (string) and get words separated by spaces.

for example: phrase=`**"i love this world love"**` BUT I need to try this WITHOUT methods or functions like SPLIT or REGEX or similar.

I need to compare 2 words and I dont know how to catch '`em in separated word1 word2 fullphrase`.

What i want is `word1="this" word2= "world"` AND CHECK if there are 2 words REPEATED

```
string frase, palabra1="",pal2="";          
bool si = false;
Console.WriteLine("Entra frase");
frase = Console.ReadLine();            
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < frase.Length; i++)
    {                
      if (frase[i] != ' ')
         {
           palabra1 += frase[i];
           if (pal2 == palabra1) si = true;                  
         }             
      else
         {                    
          pal2 = palabra1;                                                      
          palabra1 = "";                   
         }                                 
    }
if (si == true) Console.WriteLine($" SI HAY palabras seguidamente 
repetidas ");
else Console.WriteLine($"NO HAY PALABRAS REPETIDAS AQUI");
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Balastrong  palabra1 = "";
            pal2 = "";

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < frase.Length; i++)
            {
                  palabra1 = pal2;
                palabra1 += frase[i];
                if (frase[i] != ' ')
                {
                    pal2 = palabra1;             
                                                                   
                }

Comment: Can you use `IndexOf` and `Substring`?

Comment: @juharr task suposes to handle it with counters(loops) and IF /ELSE conditions..thats why is a task

Comment: Keep track of the position of the first letter of the word and the position of the space, and then use the `Substring` function.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica thanks for answer,but task says to work without strings functions

Comment: You could have a second loop to print out all characters (or create a new string) once you know the first index and the index of the string.

Comment: The idea here is that the you should not use any library code but write your own code to learn programming. Start with this simple approach and then try and make it better. Start looping the characters in the sentence and if the char is not a space, keep adding it to first word. Once you encounter a space, first word is completed and second word starts. Do it until no more chars are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use any functions(split, regex, indexOf, etc), then what you should do is loop through each character of the text, and push the currently processed segment into your word list when you reach a (white)space.

```
String testString = "This is  a test   string  ";
ArrayList words = new ArrayList();          
string currentWord = "";

foreach(char c in testString)
{
    if(Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
    {
        if(currentWord.Length > 0)
        {                   
            words.Add(currentWord);
            currentWord = "";                   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        currentWord+=c;
    }
}
```